# TSQL - SELECT TOP and UPDATE affecting more rows than expected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to understand the behavior of an `UPDATE/REPLACE` that I'm carrying out that is removing some invalid data and replacing with preferred data.

The `UPDATE` executes normally and does what it needs to do, but the rows affected are not what I expected in some cases (I'm carrying this out on multiple databases).

I've put part of the script below (The rest is essentially replicating the same function across multiple tables)

```
UPDATE TBL_HISTORY
SET DETAILS = REPLACE(DETAILS,'&QUOT','Times New Roman')
WHERE HISTORYID IN
(SELECT TOP 1000 (HISTORYID) FROM TBL_HISTORY
WHERE DETAILS LIKE '%&QUOT%')

GO
```

What I'd imagine to happen with the script above is to select the `TOP 1000` records in `TBL_HISTORY` that contain the unwanted string of data and carry out the `REPLACE`.

The result has been in cases where there are more than 1000 affected rows it will update all of them, returning a value of 1068 rows affected for example.

`HISTORYID` is the PK on the table. Am I misunderstanding how this should work? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The only way I could see this being possible is if there was a trigger on the table that did not include `SET NOCOUNT ON`. Otherwise, there is no way more than 1000 rows could be affected if `HISTORYID` is unique.

Comment: How many rows are returned if you turn the above into a `SELECT` statement? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBL_HISTORY WHERE HISTORY_ID IN (SELECT TOP [...]` ? I'm leaning towards HISTORYID is not unique...

Comment: @Shaneis : HISTORYID is PK. It has to be unique as per OP.

Comment: Agreed @PrabhatG, if the HISTORYID is the PK then it has to be unique. There has been cases though where the column thought to be the PK was not the PK. Essentially, there's no harm in checking :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the reply. There's no triggers on the tables affected and the table has one PK (HISTORYID) which is unique. I might restore a backup of the first database I saw it happen on and investigate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead(it is faster). If it still update more than 1000 rows, it is due to a trigger. If it updates 1000 rows then HISTORYID is not the only column in the primary key(composite primary key).

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT top 1000
    DETAILS
  FROM
    TBL_HISTORY
  WHERE 
    DETAILS LIKE '%&QUOT%'
)
UPDATE CTE
SET DETAILS = REPLACE(DETAILS,'&QUOT','Times New Roman')
```

Comment: That's great, thanks for this, I'll give it a go and check the performance. As far as the PK, it's definitely a single column key and there's no triggers on the table. I'll restore a backup of one of the databases 'pre-fix' to carry out a few tests. At least I'm not misunderstanding what the UPDATE should be doing. Thought I was losing the plot. If I find the reason I'll update the question.

Comment: Is the CTE (or the subquery) really necessary here? Would it not be possible to do `UPDATE TOP(1000) TBL_HISTORY
SET DETAILS = REPLACE(DETAILS,'&QUOT','Times New Roman')
WHERE DETAILS LIKE '%&QUOT%'`?

Comment: @cars10m that syntax would be valid as well